# Finding all unique possible moves of a knight

Tags: java, algorithm

we have a 8x8 board with cells starting from one, my goal is to write such a function with signature :
`public static String findPos(int i, int j, int n)` which takes parameters (i,j) the starting position of the knight on the board , and n is the total moves it will make(n>=0)

For example:

findPos(1,1,0) will return (1,1) only since with 0 moves the knight can only stay at it's own position

findPos(1,1,1) will return (1,1),(2,3),(3,2)

I have wrote not really pretty solution , however it counts duplicate positions the knight can take in the case for example findPos(1,1,2):

```
public static String findPos(int i, int j, int n) {

        if (n == 0) {
            if (i >= 1 && j >= 1 && i <= 8 && j <= 8) {
                return "(" + i + ", " + j + " )";;
            } else {
                return "";
            }

        } else {

            if (i >= 1 && j >= 1 && i <= 8 && j <= 8) {
                return "(" + i + ", " + j + " )" + findPos(i - 1, j - 2, n - 1)
                        + findPos(i - 2, j - 1, n - 1)
                        + findPos(i - 2, j + 1, n - 1)
                        + findPos(i - 1, j + 2, n - 1)
                        + findPos(i + 1, j + 2, n - 1)
                        + findPos(i + 2, j + 1, n - 1)
                        + findPos(i + 2, j - 1, n - 1)
                        + findPos(i + 1, j - 2, n - 1);

            } else {

                return findPos(i - 1, j - 2, n - 1)
                        + findPos(i - 2, j - 1, n - 1)
                        + findPos(i - 2, j + 1, n - 1)
                        + findPos(i - 1, j + 2, n - 1)
                        + findPos(i + 1, j + 2, n - 1)
                        + findPos(i + 2, j + 1, n - 1)
                        + findPos(i + 2, j - 1, n - 1)
                        + findPos(i + 1, j - 2, n - 1);

            }

        }

    }
```

My question is :How can I improve the code/recursion so it returns only unique positions it can take, because currently it also writes dublicates?

Comment: Not a great solution, but you could use a `Set`

Comment: If you want to avoid duplicates use a set to keep track of where you have been. If you can mutate the board you could set a visited flag so once a knight vists a square mark it as visited and dont visit it again

Comment: Answer given below. What is the status of the question? Solved or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you use a boolean array to keep the visited positions marked and prevent that position from being called again.

Here's the modification:

```java
   static boolean visited[][] = new boolean[9][9];
   public static String findPos(int i, int j, int n) {
      if(i<1 || i>8 || j<1 || j>8 || visited[i][j]) return "";
      else {
         visited[i][j] = true;
         if (n == 0) {
            if (i >= 1 && j >= 1 && i <= 8 && j <= 8) {
               return "(" + i + ", " + j + " )";
            } else {
               return "";
            }
         } else {
            if (i >= 1 && j >= 1 && i <= 8 && j <= 8) {
               return "(" + i + ", " + j + " )" + findPos(i - 1, j - 2, n - 1)
                  + findPos(i - 2, j - 1, n - 1)
                  + findPos(i - 2, j + 1, n - 1)
                  + findPos(i - 1, j + 2, n - 1)
                  + findPos(i + 1, j + 2, n - 1)
                  + findPos(i + 2, j + 1, n - 1)
                  + findPos(i + 2, j - 1, n - 1)
                  + findPos(i + 1, j - 2, n - 1);

            } else {

               return findPos(i - 1, j - 2, n - 1)
                  + findPos(i - 2, j - 1, n - 1)
                  + findPos(i - 2, j + 1, n - 1)
                  + findPos(i - 1, j + 2, n - 1)
                  + findPos(i + 1, j + 2, n - 1)
                  + findPos(i + 2, j + 1, n - 1)
                  + findPos(i + 2, j - 1, n - 1)
                  + findPos(i + 1, j - 2, n - 1);
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Or, you could use the BFS algorithm to achieve this quite easily. To know more about the BFS algorithm, you can use [this site](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/breadth-first-search/tutorial/). Details are in the code.(Apologies for using C++ instead of Java, I hope you'll be able to get the gist)

Here's how you can do this-

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
//This array is to check if a position is visited or not
bool visited[8][8];
//Here you're making a direction array for the move of the knight
int row[] = {-2,-1,+1,+2,+2,+1,-1,-2};
int col[] = {+1,+2,+2,+1,-1,-2,-2,-1};
//Returning the next move based on the current position and the move no
pair<int,int> nextMove(pair<int,int> curPos, int moveNo) {
    return {
        curPos.first+row[moveNo],
        curPos.second+col[moveNo]
    };
}
//Checking if the current position is in the board or not
bool validity(pair<int,int> curPos) {
    if(curPos.first<1 || curPos.first>8) return false;
    if(curPos.second<1 || curPos.second>8) return false;
    return true;
}
//BFS algorithm
string bfs(pair<int,int> curPos, int n) {
    //Making the string representation of the visited positions
    string ans = "("+to_string(curPos.first)+","+to_string(curPos.second)+")";
    queue<pair<int,int>> q;
    q.push(curPos);
    //Maintaining level so that it doesn't exceed the given "n" number of moves
    map<pair<int,int>, int> level;
    level[curPos] = 0;
    visited[curPos.first][curPos.second] = true;
    while(!q.empty()) {
        curPos = q.front();
        if(level[curPos]>=n) break;
        q.pop();
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            pair<int,int> tempPos = nextMove(curPos,i);
            if(validity(tempPos) && !visited[tempPos.first][tempPos.second]) {
                level[tempPos] = level[curPos]+1;
                q.push(tempPos);
                visited[tempPos.first][tempPos.second] = true;
                ans += "("+to_string(tempPos.first)+","+to_string(tempPos.second)+")";
            }
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int i,j,n;
    cin >> i >> j >> n;
    cout << bfs({i,j},n) << "\n";
}
```

Sample input:

```
1 1 2
```

Sample output:

```
(1,1)(2,3)(3,2)(1,5)(3,5)(4,4)(4,2)(3,1)(1,3)(2,4)(5,3)(5,1)
```